# Groovy script to read key:value from an input file

Tags: groovy, hashmap, jenkins-pipeline

I run following piece of groovy code to read `key:value` from an input file `Input.txt`

```
def var1 = 123;
def aVer = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "cat Input.txt | grep A_${var1} | cut -f2 -d':'").trim()
def bVer = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "cat Input.txt | grep B_${var1} | cut -f2 -d':'").trim()
def lVer = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "cat Input.txt | grep L_${var1} | cut -f2 -d':'").trim()
println ("a is ${aVer}, b is ${bVer}, l is ${lVer} \n");
```

**INPUT_FILE**

```
$> cat Input.txt
A_123:0.1
B_123:0.2
L_123:0.3
```

**SAMPLE_OUTPUT**

```
a is 0.1, b is 0.2, l is 0.3
```

This is just a snippet. In the dev environment, I'm running above code in a for loop for different values of `var1`.

The problem here is that the above code works fine on a `rhel60` machine but on `centos` machine, I get following error:

`script returned exit code 127`

Can anyone help me in understanding the reason for above error on a `centos` machine?

I'm also open to change this to a pure groovy code only instead of using shell commands as shown above.

Comment: `("input.txt" as File).readLines().collectEntries{ it.split(":", 2) }` would just read the whole file into one map and then you could pick your values from there.

Comment: @cfrick That looks like an answer to me, as long as the file is stored locally on the master and not the build server.

Comment: @cfrick, @Matt, the file `input.txt` is stored on the build server and not on Jenkins master. Will the code suggested by you not work if the file is not on master?